# C const pointer to const struct array as function argument

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reference

How can i make Alt.1 to work as intended by passing a pointer of an array and get the requested reference of an array in Alt.1 ?

```
struct mystruct
{
    int id1;
    int id2;
};

const struct mystruct local_struct[] = {
    {0, 55},
    {1, 66},
};

// Alt.1 i like to make this work (not working)
int get_reference_1(const struct mystruct *s){

   s = local_struct;
   return 0;
}

// Alt.2 works perfect but i like to use the return as status as in Alt.1.
const struct mystruct *get_reference_2(){
   return local_struct;
}

int main()
{
  struct mystruct *s = NULL;

  // Alt.1
  if(get_reference_1(s))
     /* Expected Fail*/
  else
     /* Expected Success*/

  // Alt.2
  s = get_reference_2()
  if(!s)
     /* Expected Fail*/
  else
     /* Expected Success*/

  return 0;
}
```

Maybe i'm thinking wrong and i need to pass a double pointer?

Edit: Corrected with 'const'.
Edit2: Updated header.

Comment: There are many duplicates. You apparently still don't understand quite well how pointers work, please read more about it. The reason it doesn't work is because `s` is local to `get_referenec_1`. You have to pass a pointer to the poitner you want to update.

Comment: why would tou call a global struct "`local_struct`"? Are you trying to confuse the enemy?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: updated with const.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is just a short example of my problem. I'm working in a bigger system which i cannot include everything. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s = local_struct;` is changing a local variable - it won't change the one in main. Pass the address of the variable and make changes to the original variable dereferencing it.

```
int get_reference_1(struct mystruct **s){

   *s = local_struct;
   return 0;
}
```

Calling it would be

```
  if(get_reference_1(&s))
     /* Expected Fail*/
  else
     /* Expected Success*/
```

Also you are making the compiler complain by assigning a `const` variable to non-const one. Here the `local_struct` is a constant `struct` declared in your code. Solution check whether you are doing the right thing - is this assignment necessary? You could also add `const` qualifiers as needed:

```
int get_reference_1(const struct mystruct **s){
   *s = local_struct;
   return 0;
}
...
const struct mystruct *s = NULL;
```

In the worst case drop the `const` qualifier.

Comment: Right now I have terrible net. My edits are slow.. I apologize.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight.: `const struct mystruct *a` is basically saying that `a` is a pointer to a const. Modifying the value of a struct will be illegal. But the pointer is free. We can make it point anywhere. So we can only read through this pointer. If we want to create a linked node by modifying some member of a struct instance then it will complain. (via `p` we will access it). Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Since OP's `local_struct` is marked `const`, we have no alternative but to produce a `const` pointer to it. Otherwise we might accidentally modify `local_struct` through a pointer to it, causing undefined behavior. The only way to keep `s` modifiable is to remove `const` from `local_struct`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight. Is the right thing to say is *pointer to const struct*? Just working my way through writing more clearly.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, the purpose is to avoid modification, therefor the const.

Comment: @coderredoc Right, `const struct mystruct *s` is a pointer to const struct.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go what you want

```
struct mystruct
{
    int id1;
    int id2;
};

 struct mystruct local_struct[] = {
    {0, 55},
    {1, 66},
};

// Alt.1 i like to make this work (not working)
int get_reference_1(struct mystruct **s){

   *s = local_struct;
   return 0;
}

// Alt.2 works perfect but i like to use the return as status as in Alt.1.
struct mystruct *get_reference_2(){
   return local_struct;
}

int main()
{
  struct mystruct *s = NULL;

  // Alt.1
  if(get_reference_1(&s))
  {  
      /* Expected Fail*/
  }
  else
  {
      /* Expected Success*/
  }   

  // Alt.2
  s = get_reference_2();
  if(!s)
  {   
      /* Expected Fail*/

  }
  else
  {
      /* Expected Success*/
  }   

  return 0;
}
```

It will execute successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this worked as well as the proposed one before.